# Phraseexpress 'wait timed out'

Tags: phraseexpress

I tried using [Phrase Express](https://www.phraseexpress.com/) for typing something into an online textbox. But everytime I use the hotkey to do so, it says that "Wait timed out".

What does that mean and how do I fix the issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Looking at the [PE documentation](https://www.phraseexpress.com/doc/) I find immediately **Delay** _This macro function waits for a specified amount of milliseconds to give applications enough time to perform automated tasks invoked by PhraseExpress, e.g. loading a website._ and other stuff. Maybe check there first. If you can't resolve it with documentation, see [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help center](https://superuser.com/help), then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1773177/edit) your question to provide more context and details.

Answer (score 0):

"Wait timed out" occurs if your phrase contains macros that do not receive the expected result within the internal wait time. Please check your macro.